# How to merge these two array into one

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could anyone please advice how to merge two arrays (same length) into one ? Thank you! The spread operator didnt work in that way..

```
let Array1 = [[A,B],[C,D]];
let Array2 = [1,2];

let Array3 = [...Array1, Array2];
```

Comment: Hi, please do come here with some piece of code you have tried ; SO is not a code writing service. You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to write a "good" question

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It was my first time asking question here. I have altered the question. and thanks for all the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) you can combine the arrays.

Try the following:

```js
let Array1 = [['A','B'],['C','D']];
let Array2 = [1,2];

const result = Array1.map((e, i) => e.concat(Array2[i]));

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `forEach` loop

```js
var arr=[['A','B'],['C','D']];
var arr2 = [1,2];
arr.map((i,j)=>i.push(arr2[j]))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !